# What is the use of Icon in the new Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

What exactly the use of Icon class in android M. Is it similar thing like `VectorDrawable` (Introduced in Lollipop).

Answer (score 1):

It's a wrapper class around different image resource types. I believe it's just meant to be a convenience class for certain situations, and make it easier to genericize the use of different image types.

One particular use case is with notifications, where there are now the methods [setSmallIcon(Icon icon)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Icon)) and [setLargeIcon(Icon icon)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setLargeIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Icon)), allowing you to set the icon using any of the static createWith* methods in the [Icon](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Icon.html) class.

Comment: Is this makes the image Scalable in different screen size?

Comment: No it's completely different than that. It doesn't support vectors, maybe it will someday?

Comment: Also, if you did need to use it with an SVG or VectorDrawable for some reason, you would have to first convert it into a Bitmap and use Icon.createWithBitmap().

Comment: *It's a wrapper class around different image resource types. I believe it's just meant to be a convenience class for certain situations, and make it easier to genericize the use of different image types.* - wasn't `Drawable` the same thing?

Comment: They're similar at the very least, the android sdk is pretty bloated IMO and I don't pretend to understand all of the api design decisions.